# How to Convert List into ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
[ [Data(name1, good) ,Data(name2,good)] , [Data(name2,good), Data(name2,bad)] ]
```

How to convert this List into ArrayList please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var list = [ [Data(name1, good) ,Data(name2,good)] , [Data(name2,good), Data(name2,bad)] ]

var arraylist = ArrayList(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well first, that is not how to define a list in Kotlin. Since there are no list literals in Kotlin.

Instead, it's like `listOf(1, 2, 3, 4,)` for a normal list, and `mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4,)` for a mutable (editable) list.

MutableList is basically an ArrayList in Kotlin. But there is still `arrayListOf()` in Kotlin.

There is also `toMutableList()` extension to most `Collection` subclasses in Kotlin

Comment: list.toTypedArray()